# BIBO stability of $y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}{x(\tau)d\tau}$

Tags: education, signal-processing

How can I prove that the LTI system with (output $y(t)$, input $x(t)$)

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}{x(\tau)d\tau}$$

is BIBO stable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $x(t) = 1{}{}{}$

Comment: You should first write down how your linear time-invariant (LTI) system looks like. Then you should be able to write down the output expressed by the input, using matrix exponential etc.. You should not use acronyms without writing them out the first time you use them.

Comment: @MrYouMath ??? That's what the OP did $H[x](t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}{x(\tau)d\tau}$. BIBO means the operator is bounded $L^\infty \to L^\infty$

Comment: @reuns: You are right, now I get what he is asking :). I thought there was something missing because the question didn't make sense as you pointed it out :).

Comment: It is **not** BIBO stable.

Comment: Hi @RodrigodeAzevedo can you explain me why please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Pick a constant input and check the output.

Comment: Thank you reuns and RodrigodeAzevedo.